# Windows - .Bat Editing Text File is missing pieces of Edit?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a .bat file that is intended to a create a text file with parameters that could be used to execute a JS file, here me out ok.

The first .Bat file you would see is a SETUP.bat, thats what creates the 2nd .bat file for startup. But when I create the 2nd .bat file (.txt at this point in time) it misses some of my edit and I dont know why?

**SETUP.bat**

```
@echo off
break>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test\START.txt"
echo set /p content=<"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test\lettercount.txt" >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test\START.txt
echo call node "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test\index.js" content >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test\START.txt
```

When its created it loses `<"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test\lettercount.txt"` and i dont know why?

I tried to do this but it didnt help either

**SETUP.bat**

```
@echo off
break>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test\START.txt"
echo cd C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test
echo set /p content=<lettercount.txt >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test\START.txt
echo call node "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test\index.js" content >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test\START.txt
```

and it still comes out as `set /p content=` instead of the thing it should be

any help?

Comment: You need to escape the **`>`** you're wanting to `echo` with a caret: **`^>`**.

Answer (score 0):

According to my comment, and simplified.

```bat
@Echo off
(Echo Set /P "content="^<"%UserProfile%\Desktop\test\lettercount.txt"
    Echo Call node "%UserProfile%\Desktop\test\index.js" content
)>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\test\START.txt"
```